# Google Signin onsuccess function does nothing when I block 3rd party cookies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, google-signin

I am building AngularJS application that uses basic Google Signin process https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/.

Everything works fine, I can sign in as a google user except I have one issue when I disable third party cookies.

When third party cookies are disabled on browser like this (Chrome)
[content settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOTMD.png) google sign in process does nothing.

More precisely I have a function that triggers on onsuccess event for google button but does nothing. Also I am not possible to catch an error so I can't workaround after this.

One thing that is happening also is that on loading google meta data when third-party cookies are disabled it raises an error

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document
```

It seems that google does everything fine like it should be on success but doesn't execute the code that is in that onsuccess function.

I tried everything and even on google developers site on Integrate Sign-in page when I click on sample sign in button it happens the same:

- If I enable cookies it returns to me "signed in as: MyName"
- If I disable cookies it returns nothing to me

The overall question is, is there a way to catch this error and work around this and not having google executes everything like it is ok and doesn't execute code that is in onsuccess function?

Answer (score 1):

Users who have third party cookies disabled [cannot access pop-up Google sign-in](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/246#issuecomment-258717271).

This is a deal breaker for us, as third party cookies are a recommended privacy practice (and the default in Safari).  Instead it's necessary to use the Google API to [generate an authentication URL](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/#generating-an-authentication-url), after which you'll get a callback with a token.